# Ledger ERROR TxSet mismatch: LCD wants [seq=2515401, hash=a0651e], LCL is [seq=2515401, hash=fb4318]

Tags: stellar-core

when starting Node after it failed to sync the ledger:
[Ledger ERROR] TxSet mismatch: LCD wants [seq=2515401, hash=a0651e], LCL is [seq=2515401, hash=fb4318]

[Ledger ERROR] It is possible that your bucket storage or database is corrupted. Restore latest backup or reset this instance to fix this issue.
current exception: std::runtime_error("txset mismatch")

thnx in advance for any help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.